# Apple Music - Allowing Explicit Content Disabled

Tags: itunes, itunes-store, apple-music

I've just started using Apple Music and searched for Metallica. And most of their albums are greyed out. After sometime searching for the answer i could see that all the Albums with the Explicit Content is greyed out.

I checked my Itunes settings and as i figured, the setting for "Restrict Music with Explicit Content" is checked.
But here is the strange part : I cant 'uncheck' the option. The option is checked and greyed out.

[image: Itunes Options]

Anyone have any idea how to uncheck that option and get access to Explicit Content?

Note: My apple account belongs to the Indian Store.

Comment: Is there a mobile device management profile installed on the computer, such as from your work? You can check this by going to System Preferences. If a Profiles icon appears in there (silver starburst with a checkmark) then one is installed.

Comment: @smoooosher Nope, this is a personal computer and only one user(admin).

Answer (score 2):

This is the reply i got after chatting with the customer team for over half an hour - Due to the laws between the countries. The iTunes Store in India does not offer explicit content on the music store!!!

Comment: am not sure, but maybe the same implies to other places. Hope i am wrong and there is a work around for this, cauz this sucks!